# I want my messagebox to pop-up in the foreground

Tags: tkinter, messagebox

I want my messagebox to pop-up in the foreground over any application I'm running. Currently it pops-up in the background. I can tell only with the notification sound.
I tried the toplevel, but I did not work.
I'm running python 3.8

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


print("Testing program")
time.sleep(5)
print("Program tested")
window=Tk()
window.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo('Successful','Script executed successfully')
window.deiconify()
window.destroy()
window.quit()
```

Comment: Add `window.attributes('-topmost', 1)` after `window=Tk()`.  Also no need to call `window.deiconify()` before `window.destroy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code for anyone who needs:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


print("Testing program")
time.sleep(5)
print("Program tested")
window=Tk()
window.attributes('-topmost',1)
window.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo('Successful','Script executed successfully')
window.deiconify()
window.attributes("-topmost", True)
window.destroy()
window.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `.destroy()` the window, then you are closing it. Also, you need to use `.mainloop()`, and if you `.quit()` it, then it won't appear at all.

So here is your code. You need to use `.attributes()` and put it on the very top.

Code:

```py
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


print("Testing program")
time.sleep(5)
print("Program tested")
window=Tk()
window.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo('Successful','Script executed successfully')
window.deiconify()
window.attributes("-topmost", True)
window.mainloop()
```